# Capitalisation of plural proper nouns

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, capitalization

Atlantic and Pacific Oceans or Atlantic and Pacific oceans? Jackson and Smith Streets or Jackson and Smith streets? Would "ocean" and "street" in these instances take capital letters as part of a compound proper noun or do they play more of an adjectival role when in plural form?

Comment: If the second element is capitalised in the singular, I see no reason not to do so in the plural.

Comment: It occurs to me that if the generic term ("ocean" or "street") appears as *part of* the proper noun, it should be capitalized: "Atlantic Ocean and Pacific Ocean," "Jackson Street and Smith Street"; but not if it appears as a generic term following the shortened form of the proper noun: "Atlantic and Pacific oceans," "Jackson and Smith streets." I seldom disagree with @KateBunting, but I'm going to make an exception in this case.

Comment: I think there is room for both styles. [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/place/Atlantic-Ocean) has the 'Atlantic and Arctic oceans', 'South Atlantic and Indian oceans' and 'Atlantic and Pacific oceans' but a [scientific paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-75115-8_16) has 'the Atlantic
and Pacific Oceans'.

Comment: I can see a case for the Brooklyn _Bridge_ or the Manhattan _Bridge_, but the Brooklyn and Manhattan _bridges_ which, I see, appears to be supported by the [Library of Congress](https://www.loc.gov/resource/cph.3c00106/)

Comment: I would say that for many people, lists can demote proper nouns to generic ones. The London Encyclopaedia (1929) mentions that in 1929 the Grand Union Canal Company joined "the Regent's _Canal_ in London, the Warwick and Birmingham, the Warwick and Knapton, and the Birmingham and Warwick Junction _canals_, to form the new Grand Union _Canal_".

Comment: The Washington Post has "the Democratic and Republican _parties_" and the New York Times has "the Democratic and Republican _Parties_". It's a style choice.

Comment: If I could find some differing style guidances I could work this all up into an answer.